# split samples by median of each column using for loop R

Tags: r, loops, split

I have a table with sample_id in rows and expression values for 100 genes in column.

| sample_id | geneA | geneB | geneC | geneD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Here is what the dat frame looks like

```
df <- data.frame("sample" = c("AB.2808","AB.2809","AB.2810","AB.2811"),
                 "geneA" = c(68381, 906 ,46575, 125489),
                 "geneB" = c(46517, 207,    78562,  1631),
                 "geneC" = c(135673,    406 ,92333, 234154),
                 "geneD" = c(146331,    330,    103819, 4596),
                 "geneE" = c(66165, 76280,  40924,  59838),
                 "geneF" = c(159261,    2610,   126598, 2669))
```

To do it on single column I use the code:

```
               df$Cluster_geneA <- ifelse(df$geneA <= median(df$geneA), "low","high")
```

I am  trying to loop  it to  generate columns with assigned "low"-"high" groups  based on each columns(gene):

```
{
df <- df[order(df[,i]),]                                
                   df[ , paste0("df$Cluster", i] )] <- ifelse(df[,i] <= median(df[,i]), "low","high")
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly.
In the output I want to add to the data frame additional columns with the low-high group assigned  to each sample:

```
Cluster_geneA=c("low","low","high", "high","low", "low")    
Cluster_geneB=c("low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high")    
Cluster_geneC=c("high", "high", "low", "high", "low", "high")
```

Thanks

Comment: Please be sure to provide reproducible examples of your data, as well as an example of what you would like the output to look like.

Comment: @Marina Melixetian - The examples don't fit together - _gene_1_ vs. _geneA_, 4 rows of 6 colums vs. 6 rows.

Comment: you can use quantcut from the gtools package. https://rdrr.io/github/r-gregmisc/gtools/man/quantcut.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach constructing a data frame with the "cluster" columns and adding that to the original frame:

```
# apply your given function to each column but the first
cf = apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) ifelse(x <= median(x), "low", "high"))
# generate the desired column names by prepending "Cluster_"
colnames(cf) = paste("Cluster", colnames(cf), sep="_")
# append the generated frame columns to the original
df = cbind(df, cf)
```